# Why Does the Definition of a Topology via Neighborhoods Include This Axiom

Tags: general-topology, definition

My question concerns the [Definition via Neighborhoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space) of a topological space. I am having trouble seeing why $(4)$ is necessary in the definition, which I'll briefly run through below.

---

Let $X$ be a set and define a function $\mathcal{N}:X \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ which assigns to each $x \in X$ a nonempty collection of subsets of $X$, which we call *neighborhoods* of $x$, satisfying the following properties:

1. If $N \in \mathcal{N}(x)$ then $x \in N$.
2. If $N,M \in \mathcal{N}(x)$ then $N\cap M \in \mathcal{N}(x)$.
3. If $N \in \mathcal{N}(x)$ then any set $Y\supseteq N$ is also in $\mathcal{N}(x)$.
4. If $N \in \mathcal{N}(x)$ then there exists an $M \subseteq N$ in $\mathcal{N}(x)$ such that $N \in \mathcal{N}(y)$ for all $y \in M$.

Define a set $U \subseteq X$ to be *open* in $X$ if $U$ is a neighborhood of all of its points.

---

As I mentioned above, I am not sure why we need $(4)$ because (I think) I can recover the standard definition of a topology via open sets just from $(1)$ through $(3)$. Assuming the definition of an open set given above we see that clearly $\varnothing$ is open because it is vacuously a neighborhood of all of its points. Moreover, $X$ is open by $(3)$. Finite intersections of open sets are open by $(2)$, and arbitrary unions of open sets are open by $(3)$.

Wikipedia mentions that $(4)$ "has a very important use in the structure of the theory", but I don't see how this is possible if I can recover the standard definition of a topology via open sets without it.

I feel that I must be missing something simple. Have I made a mistake? Do you actually need $(4)$ to recover the standard definition of a topology via open sets? If not, then how is $(4)$ important?

Comment: It is there such that $\mathcal{N}$ is a system of neighborhoods for the corresponding topology. It is true that the sets defined as *open* above would form a topology, but without (4) some elements of $\mathcal{N}(x)$ might not be actual neighborhoods of $x$ (sets containing an open set containing $x$)

Comment: Take into account that (4) is the only property that relates neighborhoods of a points with neighborhoods of another. Without it you can put in $\mathcal{N}(x)$, for some $x$ more sets, without having any effect in the corresponding topology. For example, take the indiscrete topology in $\mathbb{R}$. Define $\mathcal{N}(x)=\mathbb{R}$ for all $x\neq0$. No matter how you define $\mathcal{N}(0)$ satisfying (1)-(3), the topology that you would get by the open sets above is the same, the indiscrete topology.

Comment: @AOlov, you should turn those two comments into an answer!

Comment: @AOlov Thank you, that's what I was missing. If you don't mind me asking a question to clarify . . . Based off of what you're saying I would want $(4)$ to say, "If $N \in \mathcal{N}(x)$ then it should contain an open neighborhood containing $x$. (i.e. it should contain an $M \in \mathcal{N}(x)$ which is a neighborhood of all of its points)." What it actually says is that $N$ should contain an $M \in \mathcal{N}(x)$ such that $N$ is a neighborhood of all of the points in $M$. Are these significantly different?

Comment: You can prove it as an exercise. Given $A\in\mathcal{N}(x)$ look at $A^o=\{y\in A:\ A\in\mathcal{N}(y)\}$. Take $y\in A^o$. Then $A\in\mathcal{N}(y)$. By (4) there is $\mathcal{N}(y)\ni M\ni y$ such that $A\in\mathcal{N}(z)$ for all $z\in M$. Therefore $M\subset A^o$. By (3) $A^o\in\mathcal{N}(y)$. Therefore, $A^o\subset A$ is open.

Comment: It is a good exercise to do once in live (but probably no more than once) to prove the equivalence of the ways to axiomatize topology: Open sets, closed set, neighborhoods, Kuratowski operator (closure operator), interior operator.

Comment: Similarly, in the Kuratowski closure operator definition, it suffices to take a preclosure operator to define a topology (which is a closure operator minus the axiom $\operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{cl}(X)) = \operatorname{cl}(X)$.  What doesn't happen in this case, in general, is that the closure operator induced by this topology recovers the preclosure operator that we started with.

Comment: In addition to the definitions @AOlov mentioned, there are also the internal conditions for a collection of subsets to form an open basis of some topological space; and similarly, the internal conditions for a collection of subsets indexed by $X$ to form a system of neighborhood bases of some topological space.  The latter is arguably the "natural" way to define a topology from a metric, for example.

Comment: In axiom 4, shouldn't $M$ be nonempty?  Otherwise it seems like $M=\varnothing$ is always satisfied and the axiom doesn't seem to add any new content.

Comment: Thanks all for your input. I was stuck on making sure that I could define open sets correctly and forgot all about looking at whether or not neighborhoods defined in one perspective were the same as neighborhoods in the other perspective. @user326210 Yes it should be but since $M \in \mathcal{N}(x)$ it must contain at least $x$.

Comment: @wgrenard Oh I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. When you define topological terms using open sets as a foundation, open sets are defined axiomatically and neighborhoods are defined as any set containing an open set.
2. When you define topological terms using neighborhoods as a foundation, neighborhoods are defined axiomatically and open sets are defined as any set which is a neighborhood of all of its points.
3. These definitions coincide if you use the four axioms above.  As you point out, the first three are enough to make sure that *open set* means the same thing in both scenarios. The fourth axiom is necessary to make sure that *neighborhood* means the same thing.
4. If you exclude the fourth axiom, then your definition might allow a neighborhood (axiomatically defined) which is not a neighborhood (a set containing an open set).

   For example, take the real line $\mathbb{R}$ and define a neighborhood system axiomatically as follows. For each point $x\neq 0$, let $\mathbb{R}$ be its only neighborhood. Let the interval $(-1,1)$ and its supersets be the neighborhoods of $x=0$.  You can show that the only open sets are $\mathbb{R}$ and $\varnothing$ <sup>[*proof below]</sup>. It follows that $(-1, 1)$ is a neighborhood of 0 according to neighborhood axioms, but not a neighborhood of 0 according to open set axioms— it contains only the trivial open set $\varnothing$.

   <sup>[*]</sup> Proof of claim: if $U$ is an open set and $U$ contains $x\neq 0$, then $U=\mathbb{R}%$ because $\mathbb{R}$ is the *only* neighborhood of $x$. If $U$ contains only 0, then $U=\{0\}$, which isn't an open set because it isn't a neighborhood. If $U$ is empty, then $U$ is trivially an open set.

Answer (score 2):

You need it because the intended meaning for neighbourhood of $x$ is that it contains an open set containing $x$. Also, we want $O$ open to mean "$O$ is a neighbourhood of each of its points". Axiom (4) ties this together, and also guarantees that when we define a topology from the neighbourhood system, that the neighbourhoods for that newly defined topology are exactly the neighbourhoods we started out with; it gives a bijection between neighbourhood systems and topologies.