# The usual topology for $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I am working through some exercises in the dover book "Elementary Point Set Topology"

I am given the following axioms for a "system of neighborhoods" at x.

Let $X$ be a set and for each $x\in X$ define $\mathcal{U}_x=\{U(x)\}$ as a family of subsets of $X$ associated with $x$ such that

1. $x\in U(X)$ for each $U(x)\in \mathcal{U}_x$
2. If $U(x)\subset V$ for some $U(x)$, then $V\in \mathcal{U}_x$.
3. If $U,V\in\mathcal{U}_x$, then $U\cap V\in \mathcal{U}_x$.
4. If $U\in\mathcal{U}_x$, then there exists $V\in\mathcal{U}_x$ such that if $y\in V$, then $U\in\mathcal{U}_y$.

I am having a hard time interpreting the meaning of the fourth axiom. Please critique the following proof from an excercise in the book.

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the real line and define $(a,b)=\{x|a<x<b\}$ and define $\mathcal{U}_x=\{U|x\in(a,b) \subseteq U \ \text{for some}\ a,b\in\mathbb{R},a<b\}$,

then $\mathcal{U}_x$ is a neighboorhood system at $x$.

Proof.

1. $x\in U(x)$ for each $U(x)\in\mathcal{U}_x$ by definition.
2. Suppose that $U(x)\subset V$ for some $U(x)\in\mathcal{U}_x$. Then $x\in (a,b)\subset U\subset V$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence, $V\in \mathcal{U}_x$.
3. Suppose that $U,V\in\mathcal{U}_x$. Then $x\in(a_1,b_1)\subset U$ and $x\in(a_2,b_2)\subset V$ for some $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $(a,b)=(min\{a_1,a_2\},min\{b_1,b_2\})$. Then $x\in(a,b)\subset U\cap V$. (Here I am not sure if Im correctly interpereting the defininition of $\mathcal{U}_x$ for the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$.)
4. Suppose that $U(x)\in\mathcal{U}_x$. Choose $V=(a,b)$. Then $V\in \mathcal{U}_x$ since $x\in(a,b)\subset V$. Let $y\in V$. Then $y\in(a,b)\subset V$. But $(a,b)\subset U$ hence $y\in(a,b)\subset U$. Therefore, $U\in \mathcal{U}_y$.

Comment: 4 is a way of saying "x is in the interior of every neighborhood $U\in\mathcal{U}_x$" , without appealing to any topology (we want this because sometimes we define a topology in terms of the neighborhood systems).

Comment: Also probably a typo but in your verification of 3 you want $a=\max(a_1,a_2)$ and $b=\min(b_1,b_2)$.

Comment: Hmm, wasn't a typo. Why does it need to be $\max(a_1,a_2)$?

Comment: If $U, V$ are exactly the intervals then your $(a, b) $ is not contained in the intersection.

Comment: I thought I would need to take $\min(a_1,a_2)$ and $\min(b_1,b_2)$ to ensure that $U\cap V$ contains an interval containing $x$. Is it $\max(a_1,a_2)$ since $a_1<b_1,a_2<b_2$?

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2692678/4280) and its answers might help you understand better why this 4th axiom is needed. [My answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2771383/4280) proves the equivalence between neighbourhood spaces and topological spaces, and also shows the use of the 4th axiom.

As to your proof for the case of the real line: it's fine as to axiom 4. In terms of "neighbourhood spaces" it shows that the sets $(a,b)$ containing $x$ are the open neighbourhoods of $x$ (while sets containing open intervals containing $x$ are all neighbourhoods of $x$).

In axiom 3 (intersection), use $a_3 = \max(a_1, a_2), b_3 = \min(b_1,b_2)$ for the intersection (draw a picture): $a_1 < x$ and $a_2 < x$ iff $\max(a_1, a_2) < x$ and $x < b_1$ and $x < b_2$ iff $x < \min(b_1,b_2)$ are both easily verified.